# addTextChangedListener() on EditText in a popupwindow android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, popupwindow, textwatcher

I'm trying to have a popupwindow where I can change a delay between from which I press a button til where an image is shown up. I've read that edittext and textwatcher should to the trick but I keep getting a NullPointerExeption.

This is the part where you are in the settings and trying to set the delay.

```
else if(id == R.id.action_settings){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View setpopView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.setpop, null);
        final PopupWindow setpopWindow = new PopupWindow(setpopView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        setpopWindow.setFocusable(true);
        setpopWindow.update();

        EditText delayTime = (EditText) setpopView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        delayTime.setText("" + timerTime);
        timerTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTime.getText().toString());

        delayTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            EditText delayTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    delayTime.setText("" + timerTime);
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int  start, int count, int after) {
                    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
              }

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
              }
        });


        ((TextView)setpopWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.textDelay2)).setText("Current delay: " + timerTime + "sec");


        Button btnDismiss = (Button)setpopView.findViewById(R.id.setDismiss);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setpopWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });  
        setpopWindow.showAsDropDown(btnDismiss, 50, 50);
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setDismiss"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="         Settings"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDelay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:text="Set result delay (sec)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textDelay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text=""  >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDelay2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textDelay"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat

```
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751): Process: com.gerfort.gerfortrps, PID: 30751
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.MainActivity$14.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:413)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7472)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9246)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:957)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:501)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:216)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:243)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:382)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
11-10 03:30:00.776: E/AndroidRuntime(30751):    at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

It keeps crashing when I try to edit the text. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm very new to programming overall, so some things are not obvious to me :)

Comment: post [`logcat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) from that we can see where is the error

Comment: Sorry, forgot. It should be edited now.

Comment: debug ur code `timerTime` is *null* and no need to initialize that `EditText` again inside *addTextChangedListener*.

Comment: Now there is an error i've never sen before. I don't even have time to see what the error is because logcat is spamming "E/RichInputConnection(1362): Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text." All I hade time to see was something about allocationg memory and the program just freezes for a while then exits withot the "appname has stopped" popup.

Comment: Allthough when I set the "delayTime.setText("" + timerTime);" to a comment in "public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)" it atleast doesn't crash.

Comment: what is `timerTime` and r u trying to update `timerTime` by `TextWatcher`

Comment: timerTime is an int i use in "CountDownTimer((timerTime * 1000), 1000)" which I want to be able to edit through edittext with the code "timerTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTime.getText().toString());"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
final EditText delayTime = (EditText) setpopView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
delayTime.setText(String.valueOf(timerTime));
timerTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTime.getText().toString());

delayTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if(!s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               timerTime = Integer.parseInt(s.toString().trim());
               //delayTime.setText(String.valueOf(timerTime));
           } else {
               timerTime = 0;//set initial value of timerTime
               //delayTime.setText(String.valueOf(timerTime));
           }                
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int  start, int count, int after) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
});
```

Comment: Nvm, I didnt see you edited your code. What happends now is LogCat spams "Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8538(305KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(64KB) LOS objects, 250% free, 11MB/14MB, paused 1.589ms total 13.533ms" until the program crashes. Then the error comes after a while and it sais "java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB"

Comment: comment `delayTime.setText(String.valueOf(timerTime));` lines in `TextWatcher` run the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Some times, findViewById acts like a async call. I suggest you to change

```
EditText delayTime = (EditText) setpopView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

to

```
final EditText delayTime = (EditText) setpopView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

and remove

**EditText delayTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);**

under

```
delayTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            **EditText delayTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);**
```

Answer (score 0):

Every input you do ist replaced by "" and an NullString. The reason is that

```
delayTime.setText("" + timerTime);
```

itself calls

```
 afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

recursively and replaces the EditText with

```
"" + timerTime
```

which is null.
So don't call setText(), but try something like

```
afterTextChanged(Editable s){
   char lastCharacter = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
   if (lastCharacter == '\n') {
      timerTime = Integer.parseInt(s);
   }
}
```

'\n' represents the enter-button.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you have an infinite loop:

1. You edit the EditText
2. TextWatcher detects the EditText content has changed (in step 1), so it executes `afterTextChanged`
3. TextWatcher detects the EditText content has changed (in step 2), so it executes `afterTextChanged`
4. TextWatcher detects the EditText content has changed (in step 3), so it executes `afterTextChanged`

... and so on.

You have to control that infinite loop. The easiest way is using a flag, like this:

```
boolean disableTextWatcher;
```

.

```
    disableTextWatcher = false;
    delayTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                EditText delayTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     if (!disableTextWatcher) {
                        disableTextWatcher = true;
                        delayTime.setText("" + timerTime);
                        disableTextWatcher = false;
                      }
                  }

                  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int  start, int count, int after) {
                        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }

                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                       //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
            });
```

Comment: And take a look to Rames Palanisamy's answer too, you have several errors in your code.

Comment: It is not editable since you are rewriting the content as soon as the user writes something. What do you want to achieve by rewriting the content of the EditText?

Comment: timerTime is an int i use in "CountDownTimer((timerTime * 1000), 1000)" which I want to be ediatable through edittext for the user. I want to do "timerTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTime.getText().toString());" after the user has input the number.